# R: TM package Finding Word Frequency from a Single Column

Tags: r, tm, qdap

I've recently been working on trying to find the word frequency within a single column in a `data.frame` in R using the `tm` package. While the `data.frame` itself has many columns that are both numeric and character based, I'm only interested in a single column that is pure text. While I haven't had a problem cleaning up the text itself, as soon as I try to pull the word frequency with the `findFreqTerms()` command, I get the following error:

```
Error: inherits(x, c("DocumentTermMatrix", "TermDocumentMatrix")) is not TRUE
```

I took this to say that I needed to convert my data into either a `DocumentTermMatrix` or a `TermDocumentMatrix`, however since I only have a single column that I'm working with, I also can't create either. Error below:

```
> Test <- DocumentTermMatrix(Types)
Error in UseMethod("TermDocumentMatrix", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'TermDocumentMatrix' applied to an object of class "c('PlainTextDocument', 'TextDocument')"
```

Is there any way to get a frequency count from the single column? I've pasted my full code below with explainations for each step I took. I appreciate any help you all can give me.

```
> # extracting the single column I wish to analyse from the data frame
  Types <-Expenses$Types
> # lower all cases
  Types <- tolower(Types)
> # remove punctuation
  Types <- removePunctuation(Types)
> # remove numbers
  Types <- removeNumbers(Types)
> # attempting to find word frequency
  findFreqTerms(Types)
Error: inherits(x, c("DocumentTermMatrix", "TermDocumentMatrix")) is not TRUE
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the frequency of terms directly from your text variable if you use the `qdap` package:

```
library(qdap)
a <- c("hello man", "how's it going", "just fine", "really fine", "man o man!")
a <- tolower(a)
a <- removePunctuation(a)
a <- removeNumbers(a)
freq_terms(a) # there are several additional arguments
  WORD   FREQ
1 man       3
2 fine      2
3 going     1
4 hello     1
5 hows      1
6 it        1
7 just      1
8 o         1
9 really    1
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a corpus and term document matrix first...

```
library(tm)
a <- c("hello man", "how's it going", "just fine")
a <- tolower(a)
a <- removePunctuation(a)
a <- removeNumbers(a)
myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(a))
myTDM <- TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus)
findFreqTerms(myTDM)
```